# Generating type-stable `getfield` calls using generated functions

Tags: julia

I would like to be able to create a dispatch for a user-defined type which will essentially do an inplace copy. However, I would like to do it in a type-stable manner, and thus I would like to avoid using `getfield` directly, and instead try to use a generated function. Is it possible for a type like

```
type UserType{T}
  x::Vector{T}
  y::Vector{T}
  z::T
end
```

to generate some function

```
recursivecopy!(A::UserType,B::UserType)
  # Do it for x
  if typeof(A.x) <: AbstractArray
    recursivecopy!(A.x,B.x)
  else
    A.x = B.x
  end
  # Now for y
  if typeof(A.y) <: AbstractArray
    recursivecopy!(A.y,B.y)
  else
    A.y = B.y
  end
  # Now for z
  if typeof(A.z) <: AbstractArray
    recursivecopy!(A.z,B.z)
  else
    A.z = B.z
  end
end
```

The `recursivecopy!` in RecursiveArrayTools.jl makes this handle nested (`Vector{Vector}`) types well, but the only problem is that I do not know the fields the user will have in advance, just at compile-time when this function would be called. Sounds like a job for generated functions, but I'm not quite sure how to generate this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to bend over backwards to avoid `getfield` and `setfield`.  Julia can infer them just fine.  The trouble comes when Julia can't figure out which field it's accessing… like in a for loop.

So the only special thing the generated function needs to do is effectively unroll the loop with constant values spliced into `getfield`:

```
julia> immutable A
           x::Int
           y::Float64
       end

julia> @generated function f(x)
           args = [:(getfield(x, $i)) for i=1:nfields(x)]
           :(tuple($(args...)))
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(A(1,2.4))
(1,2.4)

julia> @code_warntype f(A(1,2.4))
Variables:
  #self#::#f
  x::A

Body:
  begin  # line 2:
      return (Main.tuple)((Main.getfield)(x::A,1)::Int64,(Main.getfield)(x::A,2)::Float64)::Tuple{Int64,Float64}
  end::Tuple{Int64,Float64}
```

Just like you can splice in multiple arguments to a function call, you can also directly splice in multiple expressions to the function body.

```
julia> type B
           x::Int
           y::Float64
       end
julia> @generated function f!{T}(dest::T, src::T)
           assignments = [:(setfield!(dest, $i, getfield(src, $i))) for i=1:nfields(T)]
           :($(assignments...); dest)
       end
f! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f!(B(0,0), B(1, 2.4))
B(1,2.4)

julia> @code_warntype f!(B(0,0), B(1, 2.4))
Variables:
  #self#::#f!
  dest::B
  src::B

Body:
  begin  # line 2:
      (Main.setfield!)(dest::B,1,(Main.getfield)(src::B,1)::Int64)::Int64
      (Main.setfield!)(dest::B,2,(Main.getfield)(src::B,2)::Float64)::Float64
      return dest::B
  end::B
```

You can, of course, make the body of that comprehension as complicated as you'd like.  That effectively becomes the inside of your `for` loop.  Splatting the array into the body of the function does the unrolling for you.

Comment: But then you can't loop over the `args` array, right? I need to then loop over it and check `typeof(args[i])` and just replace the `A.` calls with `args[i]`, but then won't that no longer be inferrable? Do I need to use a Cartesian somehow?

Comment: See my edit. You definitely don't need to use Base.Cartesian… the two examples I gave are basically `@ncall` and `@nexprs`, respectively.  I find splicing to be more approachable… and it's much more generalizable, too.